# How to arrange widgets and shapes in a QGraphicWidget with the help of a layout?

Tags: qt, layout, graphics, paint, qgraphicswidget

I have a custom QGraphicsWidgets which paints a few items and also contains some children proxy widgets:

```
//Constructor adds a child proxy button
TestWidget::TestWidget(QJsonObject testDefinition, QJsonObject testStatus, QString parentSequenceID, QGraphicsWidget *parent):
    m_parentID(parentSequenceID),
    m_testStatus(testStatus),
    m_testDefinition(testDefinition)
{
    Q_UNUSED(parent);

    m_name = m_testDefinition[displayNameStr].toString();
    m_status = m_testStatus[resultStr].toObject()[resultStr].toString();
    m_id = m_testDefinition[idStr].toString();

    m_layout = new QGraphicsLinearLayout(Qt::Vertical, this);

    //Add the pause/resume button
    auto *proxyPauseAbortButton = new QGraphicsProxyWidget(this);

    proxyPauseAbortButton->setWidget(new QPushButton(tr("Pause")));
    proxyPauseAbortButton->moveBy(20, 40);

    //Add the progress bar
    auto * proxyTestProgressBar = new QGraphicsProxyWidget(this);
    QProgressBar * testProgressBar = new QProgressBar();
    testProgressBar->setOrientation(Qt::Horizontal);
    testProgressBar->setRange(0, 100); // Let's say it goes from 0 to 100
    testProgressBar->setValue(10); // With a current value of 10

    proxyTestProgressBar->setWidget(testProgressBar);
    proxyTestProgressBar->moveBy(20, 80);

    //Add the html view
    auto * proxyTestHtmlView = new QGraphicsProxyWidget(this);
    QWebEngineView * testHtmlView = new QWebEngineView();
    testHtmlView->load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("https://www.google.com/")));

    proxyTestHtmlView->setWidget(testHtmlView);
    proxyTestHtmlView->moveBy(20, 120);

}

//Paint function draws a border, shapes, and text
void TestWidget::paint(QPainter *painter,
    const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget /*= 0*/)
{
    Q_UNUSED(widget);
    Q_UNUSED(option);

    QRectF frame(QPointF(0,0), geometry().size());
    QGradientStops stops;   

    //Draw border
    painter->drawRoundedRect(boundingRect(), 5.0, 5.0);
    //Name of the test
    painter->drawText(40, 20, m_name);

    //Status of test
    QFont font = painter->font() ;
    font.setPointSize(14);
    painter->setFont(font);
    painter->drawText(600, 20, m_status);

    //Arrow button
    QPolygonF poly;
    poly << QPointF(5, 10) << QPointF(25, 10) << QPointF(15, 20 )<< QPointF(5, 10);
    painter->setBrush(Qt::black);
    painter->drawPolygon(poly, Qt::OddEvenFill);

}
```

My question is how would you add each component (drawing/widget) to a layout, and at what time would it be appropriate to do so?   The term widgets refers to the QPushButton, QProgressBar, and QWebEngineView.  Drawings refers to the shapes and text in the paint function.

Here is a sketch of how I would like the custom widget to look like:
[image]

Comment: May I ask you to sketch a simple drawing of how do you imagine the scene with items/widget/layout.

Comment: @scopchanov Here's a link to the image.  https://imgur.com/a/hlNAe1L  The internal box is a QWebEngine View.

Comment: Please, add this information to your question.

Comment: What are those *components*? What does *drawing/widget* mean?

Comment: You guys are fast.  I updated the question with that relevant info.  Please let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: I've saw your sketch. Two things: 1. Add the picture to your question. 2. Do you want the whole item to become part of a layout or you want to arrange the widgets/shapes in it with the help of a layout?

Comment: I want to arrange the widgets and shapes with the help of a layout.  Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelJapzon, I will prepare an example for you. In the meantime, please add this last piece of info _I want to arrange the widgets and shapes with the help of a layout_ to your question.

Comment: @scopchanov Any luck with this?  Do you need further info?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MichaelJapzon, the problem is that QGraphicsItem cannot be directrly added to a QGraphicsLayout. I am thinking about a solution now.

Comment: @scopchanov,  I'm guessing no luck with this?  Just checking in...thanks for looking into this.